# An inequality involving $1/ x^a$

Tags: inequality

If $a \ge 0$, then how can I find the constant $c >0$ such that for $x \ge 1$ and $0 \le b \le x/2$, $$  \frac{1}{(x-b)^a} \le c \frac{1}{x^a}\;? $$

Comment: Manipulate the inequality so that $x$ appears only on one side. Then maximize this function of $x$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find **some** $c>0$ such that
$$
c\frac{(x-b)^a}{x^a}\geq1\ \ (1).
$$
The main observation here is that
$$
c\frac{(x-b)^a}{x^a}\geq c\frac{(x-x/2)^a}{x^a} = \frac{c}{2^a}
$$
Hence, if we require that $c\geq2^a$, then (1) is surely satisfied.